# web service event

Tags: c#, .net, service

I want to develop a web service that handle another web service's event. (C#.Net 3.5 framework)

I will develop a web service and the correspond service's event catch this service, and it will send some data to me.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant but you can create two web services with one webservice references another one.

Comment: I couldnt understand the reference issue?

Comment: you might want to read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290753%28VS.71%29.aspx